# Android NDK linking to static libary problem

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, static-libraries

```
Device: Galaxy Tab S6.    
Android Studio + plugins (latest versions as of 23/06/28, SDK 34, NDK 25.2, ...)
Development Computer: Windows 10
App type: Native C++
```

We created a Native C++, configured the library in CMakeLists.txt by adding the path to the ".a" file in the target_link_libraries block and didn't change anything else.  The library provided a number of ".a" files for different platforms and architectures (windows/linux, x86_64/arm, ...) The problem is when we choose different .a file, we get different platform/arch for the target.
For example, when we choose arm-linux-androideabi-gcc/libpayloadsdk.a, the linker runs with *--target=aarch64-none-linux-android24*, and fails with:

```
ld: error: C:/TestPSDK/app/src/main/cpp/psdk_lib/lib/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc/libpayloadsdk.a(dji_core.c.o) is incompatible with aarch64linux
```

Based on the error we switch to aarch64-linux-android-gcc, then the linker switches to *--target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi24*, and failed with

```
ld: error: C:/TestPSDK/app/src/main/cpp/psdk_lib/lib/aarch64-linux-android-gcc/libpayloadsdk.a(dji_core.c.o) is incompatible with armelf_linux_eabi
```

Any idea why the target varies when different ".a" files are used? And it seems to point to the wrong type for the chosen library.

Comment: `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` is for the 32-bit ARM7 . Aarch64 is for the (you guessed it) 64-bit ARM platform.

Comment: We tried to set the target with

        target_compile_options(MyTarget PRIVATE "-march=arm64-v8a")

or

        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -target aarch64-none-linux-android24")

But Android studio still generates the wrong target type for clang.exe.

Comment: You need to configure the targeted ABIs in Gradle first

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was able pass the Compiler error using the following Gradle settings:

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }

Comment: I suggest you post this as a self-answer for other people to find.